# Probability: $N$ dependent Bernoulli trials?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I understand the proof, but I don't see why *Bernoulli trials are mutually independent [...]* is not necessary.

[image]

Comment: This is by linearity of expectation

Comment: "We will also show that ... not necessary". This might indicate that at this stage you are not informed enough yet to digest that alternative proof. Just go on in your book and you will encounter stuff like independence of random variables and linearity of expectation.

Comment: @drhab: Thank you... But my book only mention about pairwise/mutual independent of "events" and I just realized that we are talking about different "independent"...

Comment: Can you give me the name and author of that book? It looks very nice.

Comment: *Discrete Mathematics and It's Application, Rosen, 7-th ed.* @Fakemistake

Comment: @drhab: The section "Independent Random Variables" is followed after "Linearity of Expectations".

Comment: That is quite well possible because "linearity of expectation" can be treated without "independence of random variables".

Comment: Theorem 2 of section 7.2 should prove that $X=B_1+\cdots+B_n$ has binomial distribution. I suspect they use *independent events* there. But that actually  comes to the same as using *independent random variables* $B_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a more elegant way to prove this. Making use of linearity of expectation we find:$$\mathbb E(B_1+\cdots+B_n)=\mathbb EB_1+\cdots+\mathbb EB_n=np$$ since $\mathbb EB_i=P(B_i=1)=p$ for every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Linearity of expectation also works if the $B_i$ are not independent. So this route is not only (much) more elegant but also shows that independence is not necessary.

---

Advice: If $X$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ then always think of it as a sum $X=B_1+\cdots+B_n$ where the $B_i$ are iid and have Bernoulli distribution with parameter $n$. In lots of situations that makes things more easy. This is one these situations.

Comment: then I don't understand why $\mathbb EB_i=P(B_i=1)=p$...

Comment: This is by expanding the definition of expected value into the two cases, $B_i = 1$ and $B_i = 0$

Comment: $\mathbb EB_i=0\cdot P(B_i=0)+1\cdot P(B_i=1)=P(B_i=1)$

Comment: if $B_i$ are not independent, why $\mathbb{E}B_i$ are all the same?

Comment: That is not a matter of independence but follows directly from the fact that all trials have probability $p$ to succeed. That means $P(B_i=1)=p$ for every $i$.

Comment: Thank you so much, but that's not intuitive to me. So it is possible that they're both dependent and have equal distributions? So what is/are changed after saying that they're not mutually independent?

Comment: That is possible. The ultimate example for that is the situation $B_1=B_2=\cdots=B_n$. Then the $B_i$ are not independent and all have the same distribution. Also in this situation we have $\mathbb E(B_1+\cdots+ B_n)=\mathbb EB_1+\cdots+\mathbb EB_n=np$.

Comment: Now I can appreciate your two-year-ago comment.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Congratulations with the progress you have made.

Answer (score 1):

$E[ \sum_1^n X_i ] = \sum_1^n E[ x_i] = \sum_1^n E[ x_1] = n E[x_1] = np$

Comment: but since they're not mutually independent, I don't know how to write the formula.

Comment: The first equality doesn't need a formula. It's a theorem of probability theory that applies to any sum of random variables. I'll add one more equality to try to make it more clear.

Comment: Because all the $x_i$ have equal distributions, they have equal expectations. Then you can replace any and all of them by $E[x_1]$ getting the second equality. The third equality comes from the fact that adding the same thing $n$ times is a multiplication by $n$

Comment: so it is possible that they're both dependent and have equal distributions...?

Comment: Yes, consider a bernoulli random variable B with parameter 0.5, then B and (1-B) are identically distributed but not independent